# Break and continue to another nested loop?

Tags: loops

I have one folder with 3 subfolder and in each subfolder there are 10 files without the break in the first loop it will print this

```
[['folderA', 'folderB', 'folderC'], [], [], []]
```

How can I break from the 2nd loop and continue with the first and 3rd loop ?

```
folderName = []
fileName = []
for add, directory, allfiles in os.walk("path"): #loop one 
    folderName.append([re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z ]+?)', '', i) for i in directory]) #loop 2
    break 
    for name in allfiles: #loop 3
        fileName.append(os.path.join(add, name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in directory: #loop 2
    name = re.sub(r'([^a-zA-Z ]+?)', '', i)
    if name:
        folderName.append()
```